composite unique key validation - laravel 11
Here i given below my table schema
Schema::create('yarn_work_order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('yarn_work_order_id')->constrained('yarn_work_orders');
        $table->foreignId('yarn_type_id')->constrained('yarn_types');
        $table->foreignId('yarn_count_id')->constrained('yarn_counts');
        $table->foreignId('unit_id')->constrained('units');
        $table->foreignId('color_id')->nullable()->constrained('colors');
        $table->bigInteger('unit_price', false, true);
        $table->bigInteger('total_qty', false, true);
        $table->bigInteger('org_qty', false, true);
        $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['yarn_type_id', 'yarn_count_id', 'unit_price'], 'yarn_work_order_unique_combination');
    });

I want to insert record multiple times using for loop. Here are given below my validation ruels. But unique composite validation not work. How do i find out where is my error.
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'buyer_id'                  => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:buyers,id'],
        'style_id'                  => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:styles,id'],
        'order_id'                  => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:orders,id'],
        'supplier_id'               => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:suppliers,id'],
        'company_id'                => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:companies,id'],
        'season_id'                 => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:seasons,id'],
        'type_of_wo'                => ['required'],
        'wo_date'                   => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d'],
        'items'                     => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
        'items.*.yarn_type_id'      => [
                                            'required',
                                            'integer',
                                            'exists:yarn_types,id',
                                            Rule::unique('yarn_work_order_items')
                                                ->where(function($query) {
                                                    return $query->where('yarn_type_id', $this->input('items.*.yarn_type_id'))
                                                        ->where('yarn_count_id', $this->input('items.*.yarn_count_id'))
                                                        ->where('unit_price', $this->input('items.*.unit_price'));
                                                }),
                                        ],
        'items.*.yarn_count_id'     => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:yarn_counts,id'],
        'items.*.unit_id'           => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:units,id'],
        'items.*.color_id'          => ['nullable', 'integer', 'exists:colors,id'],
        'items.*.unit_price'        => [ 'required', 'numeric'],
        'items.*.total_qty'         => ['required', 'numeric']
    ];
}


Share what error you are getting regarding validation ?does your migration file successfully created the table in db?

Yes, my migration file was successfully created the table in db.  I got this kind of error message when try to give duplicate data. Exception is throwing but validation not work. Here is exception
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1-500' for key 'yarn_work_order_items.yarn_work_order_unique_combination' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into....
Illuminate
 \ 
Database
 \ 
UniqueConstraintViolationException
